# How many ways 5 balls of different colors be put in 5 boxes with no ball in a box of the same color?

Tags: combinatorics

5 balls are there. And 5 boxes of color same as that of the balls are also there. We need to put a ball in each box. Just that we can't put ball in a box of its own color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement
it's a classic problem, I'm pretty sure you see the connection with yours (which is just a particular case). for a very direct approach to this particular one you can also look here:
http://www.algebra.com/algebra/homework/Probability-and-statistics/Probability-and-statistics.faq.question.696876.html
but i'd stick with the wikipedia article I guess

Answer (score 0):

Label the balls and the boxes with numbers 1,2,3,4,5. (same number if their color are the same.). Now your question is to find the number of permutations of the numbers 1,2,3,4,5 for which no number is its right place! This is called $Derangement$. see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Derangement.html) and also [this pdf file](http://www.math.byu.edu/~forcader/Inclusion.pdf).